# Assert in selenium in not working for me

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, assert

'Assert cannot be resolved' is displayed when i tries to insert an Assert command

```
    String menu1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("value")).getText();
    System.out.println(menu1);
    if(Assert.assertEquals(menu1,"About Us"))
    {

    }
```

Comment: Can share error trace ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please add the below import statement to your code. it may resolve your issue.

```
import org.testng.Assert;
```

assertEquals doesn't return any value.

You can't put inside a if clause. please remove if statement.

just add only the assert statement.

```
Assert.assertEquals(menu1,"About Us");
```

Answer (score 1):

The error says it all :

```
'Assert cannot be resolved'
```

The reason for this error and the solution can be either of the following:

- `import org.testng.Assert;` is missing.
- TestNG jars were not downloaded properly. You may need to download the TestNG jars and reconfigure.
- It is worth mentioning that `Assert.assertEquals()` method returns `void`. So the compiler should be complaining about the following line of code:

  ```
  if(Assert.assertEquals(menu1, "About Us"))
  ```
- If you have a requirement to catch the Pass or Fail status, wrap up the assertion in a `try-catch` block with `Throwable t` as follows:

  ```
  String menu1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("value")).getText();
  System.out.println(menu1);
  try {
      Assert.assertEquals(menu1, "About Us")
      System.out.println("Assertion Successful");
  } catch (Throwable t) {
      System.out.println("Exception raised in Assertion");
  }
  ```
- Output on success will be:

  ```
  Assertion Successful
  ```
- Output on failure will be:

  ```
  Exception raised in Assertion
  ```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use if with Assert, try it seperately. Also check whether testng is there are not,

use

```
import org.testng.*;
```

or

```
import org.testng.Assert;
```

Like this code:

```
String menu1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("value")).getText();
System.out.println(menu1);
Assert.assertEquals(menu1,"About Us");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Right Click on the folder which that we need to implement assertion just right click >>> Build Path >>> Add Libraries >>> TestNG

Answer (score 0):

Assert Error: Assert cannot be resolved.

The reason for this error is

import org.testng.Assert; is missing.

and the solution can be either of the following:

Option1:
Goto the current project working on: Project(right click on it) ---> BuildPath-->Configure Build Path--->Java Build Path--->In the Libraries Section---> Select Class Path--->Add Library--->JUnit--->Next--->JUnit library Version--->Select JUnit 5--->Click Finish

Option2:
Goto the current project working on: Project(right click on it) --->Add Libraries--->JUnit--->Next--->JUnit library Version--->Select JUnit 5--->Click Finish

Option3:
Goto the current project working on: Project(right click on it)--->Properties--->Java Build Path--->In the Libraries Section---> Select Class Path--->Add Library--->JUnit--->Next--->JUnit library Version--->Select JUnit 5--->Click Finish